# Access Areas/Help of webAPI from WebApplicaion Identity

Tags: c#, identity

I have a web application (C# mvc) and a web api (C# web api 2). In the web application I use identity to access. The web API has the help area but it is currently unprotected. How can I protect the web API help from unauthorized access and allow access to users already logged in the web application?

Comment: what kind of threat you are facing?, can you be more specific

Comment: I simply do not want to make public the business logic that can come out of the online documentation

Comment: You can use Authorize attribute provided by MVC

Comment: WebAPI and WebApplication reside in different servers and I would like to access the webapi documentation only after logging into the webapplication